# How can I play a Spotify audio track with Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, spotify

I would like to know if it's possible to play songs from Spotify with Python (version 2.7 if possible) and how.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There are several ways to interact with Spotify, where the post popular right now is the Web API. The Web API offers a lot of features, but not playback of *full* tracks.

Therefore, it doesn't matter if you're using Python, Java, C#, or whatever language. You'll still not be able to play music using the Web API. There are, however, mobile SDKs that support playback, available for both [Android](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/spotify-android-sdk/) and [iOS](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/spotify-ios-sdk/).

You can however play preview tracks (30 seconds) using the Web API. Check out [spotipy](http://spotipy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). It's one of the better Python clients, if not the best.

There are other ways to interact directly with the Spotify desktop application, but none that are supported officially by Spotify, and I can't recommend them since they may stop working at any point in time.

As [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32309322/how-can-i-play-a-spotify-audio-track-with-python/32326911#32326911) correctly states, [Libspotify](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/libspotify/) could solve this problem for you. The reason I didn't mention it is that it's deprecated. We're aiming to have a replacement for it by the end of 2015.

Comment: It's long past "the end of 2015". Is there any update?

Comment: Well, I guess there is an update now: https://developer.spotify.com/community/news/2022/04/12/libspotify-sunset/

Answer (score 4):

With [pyspotify](https://pyspotify.readthedocs.io/) you get access to all of the (old, but still working) libspotify API and you can play full tracks. It works on Python 2.7 as well as Python 3.2+ and PyPy.

Comment: Doesn’t work anymore :(